# Avoid Multiple subqueries in SQL with the same conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I have a DB of survey data that looks like this:

```
create table Products(
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(max)
)

create table Opinions(
    Id int primary key,
    ProductId int foreign key references Products(Id),
    IsEasyToUse bit default((0)),
    IsGoodPrice bit default((0)),
    IsDurable bit default((0)),
-- and so on...
)
```

I want to create a report that shows every product and a percentage of all the opinion columns from the `Opinions` table.

So far, I have been doing it the naive way:

```
select 
    p.Name,
    1.0 *
        (select count(*) from Opinions o where o.ProductId = p.Id and o.IsEasyToUse = 1) / 
        (select count(*) from Opinions o where o.ProductId = p.Id) as EasyToUse,
    1.0 *
        (select count(*) from Opinions o where o.ProductId = p.Id and o.IsGoodPrice = 1) /
        (select count(*) from Opinions o where o.ProductId = p.Id) as GoodPrice,
    1.0 *
        (select count(*) from Opinions o where o.ProductId = p.Id and o.IsDurable = 1) /
        (select count(*) from Opinions o where o.ProductId = p.Id) as Durable
from
(select Id, Name from Products) p
```

This technically works, but I am not happy with the repetition of the conditions. Also the Opinions table is growing in size so the performance issues are starting to become noticeable (it now takes around a minute with 1m rows).

Is there a way to rewrite it in a way that's faster (and easier to modify in the future in case I want to apply more filters)?

Comment: Write a after I sent trigger that increases a column with evey insert, so Thet you nly need to select the numbers needed and avoid  the count

Comment: Be aware that you'll get divide-by-zero errors for new products that don't have any reviews (opinions) yet.

Comment: What are you trying to produce? You could join the two tables, group by Product and calculate the `count()`s. Unlike the current query, the database would calculate the grand total only once.

Comment: What result do you want if there are no `Opinions` rows for a given `ProductId`?

Comment: @Charlieface All zeroes is fine. I am going to write code around the query, so the exact result format is flexible.

Comment: Then switch the `INNER JOIN` in the answers to `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: we can join and aggregate instead of executing multiples correlated subqueries.

Then: we don't need to compute the total count; instead, we can just juse `avg()`; less calls to aggregate functions should improve the efficiency of the query:

```
select p.id, p.name
    avg(case when IsEasyToUse = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as EasyToUse,
    avg(case when IsGoodPrice = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as GoodPrice,
    avg(case when IsDurable   = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as Durable 
from products p
inner join opinions o on o.productID = p.id
group by p.id, p.name
```

Depending on how your data is spread across the two tables, `apply` might offer a good alternative, since it avoids outer aggregation:

```
select p.id, p.name, x.*
from products p
cross apply (
    select 
        avg(case when IsEasyToUse = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as EasyToUse,
        avg(case when IsGoodPrice = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as GoodPrice,
        avg(case when IsDurable   = 1 then 1.0 else 0 end) as Durable 
    from opinions o 
    where o.productID = p.id
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't just the repetition of conditions. Each subquery will be executed separately.

A better option would be to join the two tables, group by product then calculate the counts. It's not possible to count based on a condition. The same thing can be done using `SUM(IIF(condition,1,0))` though:

```
SELECT p.ID, 
       MAX(p.Name) as Name,
       SUM(IIF(IsEasyToUse,1.0,0))/COUNT(*) as EasyToUse,
       SUM(IIF(IsGoodPrice,1.0,0))/COUNT(*) as GoodPrice,
       SUM(IIF(IsDurable,1.0,0))/COUNT(*) as Durable
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN Opinions o on p.ID=o.ProductID
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: Probably slightly faster to count or sum an integer and then convert afterwards rather than converting inside the aggregation `COUNT(CASE WHEN IsEasyToUse = 1 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

you could try this query ;)

```
    SELECT 
        ProductId = p.Id
    ,   ProductName = p.Name
    ,   op.GoodPrice
    ,   op.EasyToUse
    ,   op.Durable
    FROM    dbo.Products p
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  o.ProductId
            ,   EasyToUse   =   1.0 *  SUM(CASE o.IsEasyToUse WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) / COUNT(o.IsEasyToUse)
            ,   GoodPrice   =   1.0 *  SUM(CASE o.IsGoodPrice WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) / COUNT(o.IsGoodPrice)
            ,   Durable     =   1.0 *  SUM(CASE o.IsDurable WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END )  / COUNT(o.IsDurable)
        FROM    dbo.Opinions o
        GROUP BY o.ProductId
    ) op
    ON p.Id = op.ProductId
```

Comment: Grouping in the subquery will process the entire `Opinions` table, then join with Products without benefit of indexing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's not how optimizers work. SQL Server is perfectly capable of pushing predicates through a `GROUP BY` https://www.sql.kiwi/2020/05/pulling-group-by-above-join.html

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Another method for calculating percentages in which the total count can only be calculated once:

```
SELECT Name, 1.0 * EasyToUse/total AS EasyToUse,
             1.0 * GoodPrice/total AS GoodPrice,
             1.0 * Durable/total AS Durable
FROM (
  SELECT p.Name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IsEasyToUse = 1 THEN 1 END) AS EasyToUse,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IsGoodPrice = 1 THEN 1 END) AS GoodPrice,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IsDurable = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Durable,
    COUNT(p.Id) AS total
  FROM Products p
  INNER JOIN Opinions o on o.ProductID = p.Id
  GROUP BY p.Id, p.Name
) AS S
```

Comment: `MAX(p.Name)` doesn't make a huge amount of sense if `p.Id` is already unique. You may as well do `GROUP BY p.Id, p.Name`

Comment: True but I thing grouping by one column is faster than grouping by 2 !

Comment: Not true. When the column is known to be unique then the compiler factors it out either into an aggregation just on `Opinions`, or by using the internal `ANY()` aggregation, so the query plan would be the same either way. https://dbfiddle.uk/aRPZ1Hsr It would be true if there was no unique index on `Id`, as then a sort would be required, and it's faster to sort just on `Id`